# Send desktop notifications for any new chat message, not just those aimed at me

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

I created [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41933/derbyjs) and enabled desktop notifications.

Currently I don't get notified of all new messages, only those where someone mentioned me. In my opinion it's confusing and notifications should be shown for all new messages, like in Skype for example.

Can we have optional notification for any new chat message in our room, not just those aimed at us?

Comment: No, that's not expected behavior but it's legit to ask to change the behavior. Going to edit this question to reflect your actual request.

Comment: I`ve edited question again to make it more clear. If there would be significant support from community, this feature will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This *sort of* already exists. I say "sort of" because the notification control isn't very granular, but I believe you could get it to do what you want by setting notifications to "visible room":

[image]

The desktop notifications match the sound notification settings. The downside is that switching to "visible room" would kill any notifications you'd get from other rooms you're in. (I think. It just occurred to me that I've never changed this setting from it's default.)

This isn't to decline your feature request here - we could certainly use more specific notification controls, ideally on a per-room basis.

Comment: Does it mean that if I choose "visible room" then I would not get notifications from other rooms if some one mention me?

Comment: Also "Sound notifications" and "Desktop notifications" are confusing. And it`s hard to find notification options. Notifications are very important for chat, it should be more clearer.

Comment: I think that's what it means, yes.